# What's the word for telling on someone, or inform against them?

Tags: single-word-requests

The informal word for telling on people is "dobbing" (and we call that person a "dibber-dobber", at least here in Australia.

Is there an actual word for it?

Example: *Sue went to my mother and told on me when I said that I was having an abortion. Sue is such a [insert word].*

Comment: Actual word, **informer**

Comment: @NVZ There is no context in this question. I think it is always the first thing to do to ask if the OP can write an example sentence where the word would be used. I think the question asks for a verb, not a noun and all the answers except for one are suggesting nouns. We should not answer any question without any context or example sentence. Voting to close it.

Comment: @E.Groeg Can you write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: related: **1** [A word for someone reporting about other people to the government](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163603/a-word-for-someone-reporting-about-other-people-to-the-government) **2** [What is the name for a person who betrays their country?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/206831/what-is-the-name-for-a-person-who-betrays-their-country) **3** [What does it mean to “squeal on someone”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23430/what-does-it-mean-to-squeal-on-someone)

Comment: If you would like the question to be reopened, please supply greater detail in your question, and follow the tips on writing a good word or phrase request.

Comment: Okay guys, I added an example. I thought the question was clear enough.

Comment: "Informer" is only used within the context of criminal investigation (where they would often be called a CI, or "Confidential Informant").  You wouldn't normally say that a woman "informs on" her sister, to use the OPs example.

Comment: Based on your example, I'd suggest **tattle-tale, telltale**, etc.

Comment: What has "not being able to keep secrets" to do with "ratting on people?"

Answer (score 3):

**Inform** (on somebody) — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inform)

> *verb* to give information (as of another's wrongdoing) to an authority
>   
> *"informed on a member of his own gang"*

- *He **informed** on the gang.*
- *He's been **informing** on us!*

Related to the noun **Informer** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/informer)

> *noun* a person who gives information to the police about secret or criminal activities
>   *"the informer who told the police about that conspiracy has angered a lot of dangerous people"*

or **informant** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/informant)

- *She's an **informer**.*
- *She's an **informant**.*

**EDIT:** For the added example in OP, I'd suggest **tattle-tale, telltale**, etc. as mentioned in other answers. *"a person, especially a child, who reveals secrets or informs on others"*

> *"Sue went to my mother and told on me when I said that I was having an abortion. Sue is such a ____."*

Answer (score 2):

**Rat** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rat)

> *informal, verb* to tell someone in authority (such as the police) about something wrong that someone has done : to betray someone
> *"The teacher knows what we did, which means that somebody ratted."*

From [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rat)

> *informal, noun* 2.1 An informer
> *"he became the most famous rat in mob history"*

**Snitch** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snitch#snitch__10)

> *informal, noun* An informer
> *"they thought he was a plant or a snitch"*
>
> *informal, verb* 2. *(no object)* Inform on someone
> *"she wouldn’t tell who snitched on me"*

Answer (score 2):

A person telling on someone may be called a rat, mole, fink, stoolpigeon, tattle-tale, or narc, with each subject to being rendered a verb: ratted, narced, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The formal word is **informing**, see [NVZ's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/335434/15679).

Alternatively, there's **whistle-blowing**, which comes from the noun *whistle-blower*:

> one who reveals something covert or who informs against another <pledges to protect whistle–blowers who fear reprisals — Wall Street Journal>
>
> - *whistle–blowing* (noun)

[(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whistle-blowing)

- *He **blew the whistle** on the gang.*
- *He's been **whistle-blowing**!*
- *She's a **whistle-blower**.*

Various other informal ones:

- *ratting out*
- *telling on*

Comment: I agree with this answer. The question seems to be asking for a verb, not a noun. +1)

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people have given you a noun. It seems to me you asked for a verb. In the US, we often say **tattle**, although it usually applies to children, or childish behavior in adults. It's an aspersion on the **tattler**. Or, that's how it used to be. I'm old, and the language is quickly outgrowing me.

I notice that one of the answers uses the words **rat** and **snitch**. Funny, these two words are both nouns and intransitive verbs, and with help, transitive verbs. That is, a **rat** will **rat**, or will **rat on** you (or even **rat you out**), and a **snitch** will **snitch**, or **snitch on** you (I've never heard anyone say **snitch you out**).

Answer (score 1):

> [telltale](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/telltale) Pronunciation: /ˈtɛlteɪl/ ; [telltale](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/telltale)
>   …
>   1 A person, especially a child, who reports others' wrongdoings or reveals their secrets.

See also:

> [tell·tale](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/telltale) (tĕl′tāl′) n. (TFD)
>   1. One who informs on another; a talebearer.
>   …

*telltale* (ˈtɛlˌteɪl) n
1. a person who tells tales about others
(syn.) *tattletale, blabbermouth, talebearer, taleteller, tattler, tattletale
gossiper, gossipmonger, newsmonger, rumormonger, rumourmonger, gossip* - a person given to gossiping and divulging personal information about others 
…
*squealer* (informal), *snitch* (informal)

Answer (score 1):

> **Grass**. British informal A police informer.
> Perhaps related to the 19th-century rhyming slang grasshopper 'copper'
>
> Example Sentences:
> He then asked who the drug dealer was and when he found out he said, 'I wouldn't do it for him anyway because he's a **grass** and his supplier's a grass.' — [O-D](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grass)

**Grass** can also be used as a **verb**.

Also there is a relatively new term a supergrass.

> **Supergrass** l British informal
> A police informer who implicates a large number of people: both turned supergrass and were the main prosecution witnesses — O-D